# CSS display table vertically and expand horizontally when overflow

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

, and I want display the table like this:

```
+-----------+
| title     |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  4  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  5  |
+-----+-----+
|  3  |  6  |
+-----+-----+
```

How do I get this done with css/sass without using javascript and changing HTML structure?

Comment: Can you change `HTML` structure or it is fixed?

Comment: I don't think you can change HTML structure using CSS only, you need a script language to alter it or generate the code you desire.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Hi! Yes, it can be changed but I want all <td> stay in a <tr>

Comment: Use CSS grids..

Comment: @Oriol Do you mean grid system like bootstrap?

Comment: @Abood How about changing a little but still keep all <td> in one <tr>?

Comment: No. I mean [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/).

Comment: @LynnChen I've added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css3 Columns with following `HTML` structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  ....
  ....
  <li>n</li>
</ul>
```

With css as below:

```
.custom-list {
  list-style: none;
  column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```css
.custom-list {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-list li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">title</div>
<ul class="custom-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

However if you can't change structure you need to override default behavior of `<tr>` and `<td>` and apply css3 columns here as well.

```css
.custom-table {
  text-align: center;
}
.custom-table thead th {
  text-align: left;
}
.custom-table tbody tr {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  display: block;
}
.custom-table tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 32px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But it won't be a grid. If some cell has different height, the layout will break.

Comment: @Oriol yes, I agree in general it might not be the best solution but as all cells have just numbers and OP wants to keep the current structure so it might work for this particular situation.

Comment: @Oriol In my case, the cells have same height for now but I don't know whether the will be a situation that have different height

Comment: @Muhammad Usman I found out that `column-count` is only supported above ie10. How about ie9?

Comment: @LynnChen Yes IE9 doesn't support column count. You may style them differently for IE9 otherwise you have to change `HTML` structure for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

If someone find's a way it would be rather ugly and not really according to the original idea of CSS.

Actually if CSS would provide it, I would find it awkward because that's not the idea of CSS.

if you can answer, why the table can't be resorted or why you cannot use  javascript we might understand the necessity a little better.

Comment: How about changing a little and still keep all <td> in one <tr> ?

Comment: and what would you expect if one or more td's are added?

Comment: seperated <td>s into 2 columns equally and when the amount of <td> is odd the left column will have 1 more <td> compare to right column. For example, if there are 7 <td>  left column have 1-4 and right column have 5-7 :)

Answer (score 1):

this may be a solution,but better to change the html structure

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
table,tbody,tr{
 width:100%;
}
tr{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
}

th{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:orange;

  }

td{
 display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:50%;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:steelblue;
  border:1px solid #333;
  

}

td:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-top:20px;
}
td:nth-of-type(4){
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the order I want is top to bottom then left to right

Comment: you can use flex layout to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

I have change the table structure is this something you want done

https://jsfiddle.net/qLgxrob1/1/

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th colspan=2 class="text-center">title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer but I want all <td> in a <tr> :)

Comment: you mean you want them on only a single tr ? I see .

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to do that with css! only way is to change html structure by adding colspan atribute to your th element

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with no changes to the markup by using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), overriding the default `display` property of the `tr`.

The tricky part is reordering the cells as it requires an individual rule for each `td` so, if you've more than a few cells, this could become quite cumbersome.

```css
tr{
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #666;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
th,td{
  border:1px solid #666;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#000;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
}
th{
  flex:1 1 100%;
  font-weight:normal;
  padding:5px;
}
td{
  flex:1 1 50%;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
}
td:nth-of-type(2){
  order:4;
}
td:nth-of-type(3){
  order:6;
}
td:nth-of-type(4){
  order:3;
}
td:nth-of-type(5){
  order:5;
}
td:nth-of-type(6){
  order:7;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```